# Callbacks and returning values

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm stuck with two external libraries and using them together. One only has an async interface and the other requires me to return a value from the callback.

```
// this function is called as a callback from an external library
// it is required that the function returns a certain value
function onevent()
{
    // the callback for the "thirdparty.foo" function
    // with the result that must be returned from onevent
    function ondone(result) {
        // ???
    }
    // this is a call to a third party library that only has this asynchronous interface
    thirdparty.foo(ondone);
    // ??? return result;
}
```

JavaScript is pretty new for me and I was unable to find any solution for this problem.

I'm looking to something to be able to wait for the completion of `ondone` before returning from `onevent`. Comparable from C++ would be `.wait` or `.get` from a `std::future`.

Comment: I fear that this might be impossible. If you are doing AJAX then maybe there is an async flag you can set to true but in general there is no way to wait until the async function completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One only has an async interface and the other requires me to return a value from the callback.

That's a problem **if** you have to use the one providing an async interface to satisfy a callback from the one that doesn't. If you do, you simply cannot use them together. There is no way to make the callback from the one expecting a value *returned* to it by the callback wait for an asynchronous event to complete.

E.g.:

```
doSomethingExpectingReturnValueFromCallback(function() {
    // You cannot use an asynchronous API here to get the value you return
});
```

If the synchronous lib understood promises (similar to `std::future`), then you could return a promise, but it doesn't sound like it does.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. I wanted to use javascript-bcrypt which only gets me the result in a callback, but I'll have to look for something else or fiddle with it then. Thanks for the answer!